# Print with column name or tabular view in web browser SQLSRV - php

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I getting my output from a `sqrsrv` SQL server connection using `php`. I can print the rows of each column, however, I can not print headers for those rows. How do I get the headers/column names when I view in my browser (localhost)?

I have my output in browser like this,

```
Joseph   Alaba    Good
Craig    Nelson   Avg
Benjamin Hennepy  Avg
...
```

I need like this, how I would have in Management Studios (With FName, LName and Staus headers),

```
 ---------------------------
 |FName    |LName    |Status|
 ---------------------------
 |Joseph   |Alaba    |Good  |
 |Craig    |Nelson   |Avg   |
 |Benjamin |Hennepy  |Avg   |
 ...
```

After connecting to Database, I use like this to select and print,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
 echo $row['Fname'].$row['LName'].$row['Status']."<br/>";
}
```

I have been searching, could not find the code to print headers in `echo` statement. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`sqlsrv_field_metadata()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-field-metadata.php). It works with statements created with both `sqlsrv_prepare` and `sqlsrv_query`. It returns an array of arrays which contain the metadata for each field that is returned by a query.

You could use it like so:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

foreach(sqlsrv_field_metadata($stmt) as $field){
    echo $field['Name']; // The Name key provides the column name
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['Fname'].$row['LName'].$row['Status']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: thanks, this seems to be printing the header/column, but everything prints right next to each other, `FName   LName   Status Joseph` etc. IS there a way to break them by column?

Answer (score 0):

`echo 'Fname'.'LName'.'Status'."<br/>";`

Comment: I tried this, it just repeats the same variable name like `Fname`, `LName` etc.. and `row` should be there I am referencing.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Please update your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)